# TypeError XXX is not a function in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use a service in my NodeJS api to make my API easier to test, but when I inject the service (class) it tells me the method `getTasks()` doesn't exist.

**ROUTE**

```
const TodoService = require('../../services/todo');
const todo = router => {
  router.get('/tasks', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const { message, tasks, status } = await TodoService.getTasks();
      return res.status(201).json({ message, tasks, status });
    } catch (e) {
      return next(e);
    }
  });
};

module.exports = todo;
```

**SERVICE**

```
const TaskModel = require('../models/task');

class TodoService {
  async getTasks() {
    try {
      const tasks = await TaskModel.find();

      return {
        message: 'Fetched posts successfully.',
        tasks: tasks,
        status: 200
      };
    } catch (err) {
      if (!err.statusCode) {
        err.statusCode = 500;
      }
      next(err);
    }
  }
}

module.exports = TodoService;
```

When I go to `http://localhost:3000/api/tasks` I get this error:

> TypeError: TodoService.getTasks is not a function

Comment: `getTasks` is a method on an *instance of `TodoService`*  - you haven't created one, i.e. like `new TodoService()` - either declare getTasks as `static async getTasks` or don't make TodoService a class, instead write `var TodoService = {` etc

Comment: nice that worked. Feel free to put it as an answer for you to get the points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getTasks` is a method on an *instance of `TodoService`*  - you haven't created one, i.e. like `new TodoService()`

either instantiate an instance

```
await new TodoService().getTasks();
```

or, make getTasks `static`

```
const TaskModel = require('../models/task');

class TodoService {
  static async getTasks() {
    try {
      const tasks = await TaskModel.find();

      return {
        message: 'Fetched posts successfully.',
        tasks: tasks,
        status: 200
      };
    } catch (err) {
      if (!err.statusCode) {
        err.statusCode = 500;
      }
      next(err);
    }
  }
}

module.exports = TodoService;
```

or given the fact that TodoService doesn't look like it should even be instantiated, and this is the way I'd do it with the code you've shown,  make TodoService a simple Object

```
const TaskModel = require('../models/task');

const TodoService = {
  async getTasks() {
    try {
      const tasks = await TaskModel.find();

      return {
        message: 'Fetched posts successfully.',
        tasks: tasks,
        status: 200
      };
    } catch (err) {
      if (!err.statusCode) {
        err.statusCode = 500;
      }
      next(err);
    }
  }
}

module.exports = TodoService;
```

Comment: does it have any pros or cons the second way you are suggesting for unit testing or is essentially the same? I'm new to nodejs

Comment: really depends on usage - I couldn't tell you which is "better" because to me the last two (I added one in the meantime) to me are pretty much the same

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you sir!